# How to replace all spaces in .txt file using SED in Cygwin

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin

I have a huge .txt file that I want all spaces, line-breaks, indentations etc removed. It should literally be one long string.

I tried

> sed -i 's/\ //g' test.txt

but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "s/[[:blank:]]//g;H
$ {x;s/\n//g;p;}"
```

The H than $ are needed if you want to include New line due to fact that sed treat by default line by line (so no new line inside a line). The -n  and p  are needed to avoid double display with use of H

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work ok for me:

```
[~/Desktop]
==> cat test.txt
the quick brown fox

[~/Desktop]
==> sed -i "s/\ //g" test.txt

[~/Desktop]
==> cat test.txt
thequickbrownfox
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. For clarity, I don't even want the spaces between words. So 'the quick brown fox' should become thequickbrownfox

Comment: Strange that it's not working. It worked fine for me (both single and double quotes). Maybe superuser would be a better forum.

Comment: Hmmm. Upon closer inspection it did remove the spaces. However, I also want it to remove all line-breaks so its just one giant jumble of characters

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using " " directly is hard and especially when you use double quotes (which involves that bash will interpret the string before passing it to sed).

```
sed -i -e 's/\s//g' file.txt
```

... should work (it works for me). "\s" means all whitespace characters, and with single quotes '', for bash not to interpret it before you passing it to sed.

Comment: The `\s` only means all whitespace characters in newer versions of GNU sed. It's not part of BRE.

Answer (score 0):

While you use cygwin I think your OS is windows, then you don't need to use bash to implement your goal. Just open your txt file with the text editor, and replace the while space with nothing, then all of the whit space in you txt file will be removed.

This method can meet almost all kinds of removal. And also can apply in excel or word and so on.

Good luck!

Comment: This is not a recommended way, esp if 1. the file is huge - your text editor may hang. 2. If your file contains non-printable data & editors like notepad will corrupt entire file, if saved. 3. The file is generated at run time & you need to filter it (remove spaces in this context) - automatically; typically useful when the file is generated frequently.

Comment: @anishsane yes, you're right. But if it is just some easy job, this works well. And about non-printable data we can copy it and replace then(like TAB or some starlike ).

Comment: By non-printable, I mean chars like ascii value > 0x80, or ascii=0x3 etc.

Comment: Besides, since the OP asked for cygwin solution, when the text editor method was so obvious for windows users, I am speculating that (s)he wants to put the commands in a script.